# Flex 4 Keeping Data Providers In Memory

Tags: flash, apache-flex, memory

I am working on a modularized Flex application, and I am trying to cut-down on the amount of client-server interaction.

Every time a module is opened, a request is made to a web service to get values to bind to the Flex form.  If a user closes the module, and then reopens it at another time during their session, the same web request will be made.

Since this data is static, i.e. not changing, I am thinking about creating global variables to hold the data providers.  On the initial application load, a series of web service calls will be made to fill all needed data providers.  Then, any time a module is opened, it can use these global providers instead of making unnecessary and repeated requests.  These are NOT going to be huge providers, so I don't think browser memory should be a concern.

Does anyone have a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For static non-changing data; hard code it.

If you must ping the remote server for this data; implementing a caching mechanism to reduce back and forth overhead is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  A quick google of "flex object caching" pointed me in the right direction.